# Does milvus2.0 support restful API?

Tags: milvus

Milvus1.x can support restful API. I can find some docs from [here](https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/tree/1.1/core/src/server/web_impl).
But I don't find restful API docs for Milvus2.0.

Comment: Off-site resource requests are off-topic

Comment: Please reqd [ask] and take a [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from this [page](https://wiki.lfaidata.foundation/display/MIL/Milvus+2.X+Roadmap+and+Time+schedule#:%7E:text=Supports%20Restful%20APIs) that restful API is under development.